# how to pass user credential to webClient()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using `WebClient`, instead of `HttpClient`, to make some WebAPI calls from MVC controllers.  However, I keep getting `401 Unauthorized` error. In the following code, I initialize the `WebClient` with the `UseDefaultCredentials = true`.  I still get the error.

```cs
_lazyClient = new Lazy<WebClient> (() => new WebClient {
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
});
```

```cs
public static class WebClientWrapper 
{
    static private string _baseUrl;
    static private Lazy<WebClient> _lazyClient;

    static private WebClient Client() 
    {
        if (_lazyClient == null) 
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("WebClient has been disposed");
        }

        //string myUri = _baseUrl;
        //CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
        //cc.Add(new Uri(myUri), "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
        //_lazyClient.Value.Credentials = cc;
        return _lazyClient.Value;
    }

    static public T Execute<T> (string baseUrl, string urlSegment) 
    {
        _baseUrl = baseUrl.Trim('/');
        _lazyClient = new Lazy<WebClient> (() => new WebClient {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        });

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Client().DownloadString(_baseUrl + '/' + urlSegment.TrimStart('/')));
    }
}
```

Comment: What authentication are you using in the WebAPI?  `UseDefaultCredentials` won't work for you, as it's probably using the credentials that the web server is running under, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Thank you. The IIS s is using Windows Authentication.  The web.config has impersonation enabled.

Comment: I also used HttpClient in other controllers.  They all have UseDefaultCredential =true and successfully retrieve data through WebAPI.